# Parse phase of sql statement Oracle and TOAD

Tags: performance, oracle, sql-execution-plan

Is it only the explain plan to look in when tuning a large sql string? 
Because when I push Ctrl+E in TOAD for Oracle (which generates explain plan), this takes several seconds. Does TOAD do anything more than generating the explain plan, or is it really so that the parse phase takes 2-3 seconds for that specific sql statement?

I really can't see how to optimize the sql string anymore when looking at the explain plan. So I thought maybe there is something going on BEFORE executing the plan?

thanks in advance
Martin (newbie oracle tuning expert)

Comment: why does 2-3 seconds to get an explain plan worry you?

Comment: Compare performance of TOAD with SQL*Plus. Then you'll see if TOAD is taking time to do something extra, or if it's just the database taking time to parse the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explain plan doesn't tell you everything - Oracle just tells you an *estimate* of the costs of your query.
To get the *real* costs of your query, you have to actually execute it and check the performance afterwards (e.g. using tkprof).
I'd recommend checking out Asktom, e.g.
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8764517459743
 and getting a good book on Oracle performance tuning (e.g. "Effective Oracle by Design" by Tom Kyte).